# Inserting multiple dictionary objects into a MySQL database using python and MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

I have been struggling with this for hours and I feel like crying now as I'm unable to fathom out what is happening.

Here is a simplified version of my data:

```
mydata = [ { 'id': 123, 'thing': 'ghi', 'value': 1 }, { 'id': 456, 'thing': 'xyz', 'value': 0 } ]
```

This is the code I have:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = None
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testing', 'anothervalue', 'andanother');
cur = con.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO `tablename` ( `id`, `thing`, `value` ) VALUES ( %(id)s, %(thing)s, %(value)s )"
cur.executemany( sql, ( mine for mine in mydata ) )
con.close()
```

What I expected to happen was that 2 rows would be inserted into **tablename**.  What actually happens is that the script executes without any errors and no rows are inserted.

What am I doing wrong?  If I do a single INSERT by hand it inserts into the table properly so I think know its not a problem with the MySQL database but rather how I'm passing the variables into the database.

An additional question I have is how to I insert **value** as a float?  At the moment I have the definition of **value** in the table as **TINYTEXT NOT NULL**, I would like this to be **FLOAT NOT NULL** but I'm not sure how to handle the substition above.

Comment: mydata is a list of dictionaries (as defined above).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to use a generator to loop over `mydata`. Just pass in `mydata` directly:

```
cur.executemany(sql, mydata)
```

The database adapter will loop over `mydata` for you and a generator expression only inserts a needless extra loop.

If you do not get any error messages but there are no changes either, check the following:

- Make sure you commit the transaction; run `con.commit()` after the `.executemany()` call.
- *Tripple-check* that `mydata` is not empty.

The database adapter will correctly handle float values for you; if a column is marked as `FLOAT NOT NULL` and you pass in a Python float value for that column, Things Just Work. That's what SQL parameters are for, handling quoting of different datatypes correctly.

Comment: When I do that nothing happens.  The script executes and finishes without an error, no rows are inserted.

Comment: @user1464409: Please share what `mydata` is then.

Comment: mydata = [ { 'id': 123, 'thing': 'ghi', 'value': 1 }, { 'id': 456, 'thing': 'xyz', 'value': 0 } ]

Comment: @user1464409: I *suspect* that `executemany()` does not support dictionaries. Checking the code now.

Comment: @user1464409: Are you *100%* certain that that list is not empty? The code certainly handles `%(name)s` and `dict` interpolation properly for both `.execute()` and `.executemany()`.

Comment: By default, Auto-Commit is enabled in MYSQL....Most probably he has it disabled in his installation.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Auto-Commit is enabled in MYSQL. To check the current configuration in your setup, please connect to your MYSQL instance and execute the following.

```
mysql> select @@autocommit;    
+--------------+    
| @@autocommit |    
+--------------+    
|            1 |    
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If the value is 1 then it is enabled...Else not....

To be honest, your original snippet works fine for me. So this could mostly be an auto-commit issue.

Try adding the following line just before `con.close()` in your original code.

```
con.commit()
```

You could still give a try with my snippet posted below if autocommit is enabled...Are you able to change the mydata list members from Dictionary to Tuple type? If yes then please see if the following snippet helps you.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

mydata = [ { 'id': 123, 'thing': 'ghi', 'value': 1 }, { 'id': 456, 'thing': 'xyz', 'value': 0 } ]
mydata_modified=[ (123, 'ghi', 1 ), ( 456, 'xyz', 0 ) ]

con = None
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testing', 'anothervalue', 'andanother');
cur = con.cursor()

cur.executemany( """INSERT INTO tablename ( id, thing, value ) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s )""", mydata_modified )
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

just an FYI to expand on Guddu, you can convert your dictionary to tuple type by doing something like:

```
mydata_modified = []
for x in mydata:
   mydata_modified.append(tuple(x.values()))
```

Comment: wrong, because the order of ``x.values()`` can be not the same as expected sql query

Comment: so wrong. the order is not gurantteed. I think python is not that dynamic friendly. Just make a tuple and sorted the tuple fields in order.

Answer (score 0):

```py
tuple_mydata = [tuple(mine.values()) for mine in mydata]
cur.executemany(sql, tuple_mydata)
```