# Parsing large JSON - Python

Tags: python, json

I'm using a [Public API](https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list2), which list all the curses from coursera. The json is around 8MB. Now, my question is how I parse the json efficiently and save the content inside my DB.

Here is my code :-

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list2') # Is getting all the information at once, the standard way of doing it or should I get in chunks?
print r.json()

# Now to save the details, should I use a NoSQL DB.
# I've little experience of using a NoSQL DB, hence for building an app that list all coursera courses, 
# saving data inside a Mongo will be a good choice or not.
```

Thanks

Comment: Way too broad of a question. You've already parsed it and there are a thousand ways to save it.

Comment: Do some research: learn about different kinds of NoSQL databases, compare their features with what your app needs, choose one and learn how to use it with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to get into the debate of SQL vs. NoSQL. Also, I don't feel sufficiently informed about your project to give you advice. But it seems that you have some experience with SQL, and that you'd like to:

- explore the json to see what you can use in your app
- figure out an appropriate database schema
- parse the json and insert them in the database you've just created.

I haven't searched, but maybe there's documentation by coursera on the information provided by this http request. You could use that to guide your model development.

If not, or if you feel inclined to jump into the data and figure out the model empirically, the good news is that requests.json() will decode the json content to a dictionary automatically.

To explore this dict, you can use the dict.keys() method

```
>>> r.json().keys() # returns the following line:
dict_keys(['unis', 'insts', 'cats', 'topics', 'courses'])
```

Do that recursively to get a feel of what's underneath each node. If you hit lists, then examine a couple of these lists. The lists would likely translate to rows in the sql world. If the lists contain dicts, then it'd give you an idea of what the field names would be. If further, the dicts inside this list have nested dicts, that might indicate relationships

For instance,

```
>>> r.json()['unis'].keys() # gives me the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

So, I tried,

```
>>> pp.pprint(r.json()['unis'][0]) # which gave me the first record
{'abbr_name': 'Stanford',
 'banner': 'https://coursera-university-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/73/a47990ea7c11e3b00589d092602f0d/Stanford-University-Banner-LRG.jpg',
 'class_logo': 'https://coursera-university-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/21/9a0294e2bf773901afbfcb5ef47d97/Stanford_Coursera-200x48_RedText_BG.png',
 'description': 'The Leland Stanford Junior University, commonly referred to '
                'as Stanford University or Stanford, is an American private '
                'research university located in Stanford, California on an '
                '8,180-acre (3,310 ha) campus near Palo Alto, California, '
                'United States.',
 'display': True,
 'favicon': 'https://coursera-university-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/dc/581cda352d067023dcdcc0d9efd36e/favicon-stanford.ico',
 'home_link': 'http://online.stanford.edu/',
 'id': 1,
 'landing_page_banner': 'https://coursera-university-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/6f/75dd30dd5911e38988193a0e8ad8fe/Stanford_Coursera-200x48_RedText_BG.jpg',
 'location': 'Palo Alto, CA, United States',
 'location_city': 'Palo Alto',
 'location_country': 'US',
 'location_lat': 37.4418834,
 'location_lng': -122.14301949999998,
 'location_state': 'CA',
 'logo': 'https://coursera-university-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/d8/4c69670e0826e42c6cd80b4a02b9a2/stanford.png',
 'name': 'Stanford University',
 'partner_type': 1,
 'primary_color': '#8C1515',
 'rectangular_logo_svg': 'https://coursera-university-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/d6/cb68d0d09b11e3a575e17d6a22968b/SUSig_StnfrdOnly.svg',
 'short_name': 'stanford',
 'square_logo': 'https://coursera-university-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/e3/cebbb0d0a311e39b31794df7e5d956/Coursera-SUSig_StnfrdUStack_SQ.png',
 'square_logo_source': 'https://coursera-university-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/e2/c49eb0d0a311e3ad37254033038522/Coursera-SUSig_StnfrdUStack_SQ.png',
 'square_logo_svg': 'https://coursera-university-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/e0/0dbc10d0a311e3ad37254033038522/Coursera-SUSig_StnfrdUStack_SQ.svg',
 'website': '',
 'website_facebook': '',
 'website_twitter': '',
 'website_youtube': ''}
```

From here on, naively, I would create a table called coursera_unis with the following fields as returned by this line of code:

```
>>> r.json()['unis'][0].keys()
dict_keys(['website_facebook', 'location', 'website_twitter', 'square_logo', 'favicon', 'id', 'website', 'location_lng', 'logo', 'location_lat', 'partner_type', 'short_name', 'website_youtube', 'square_logo_svg', 'banner', 'primary_color', 'location_country', 'rectangular_logo_svg', 'square_logo_source', 'name', 'landing_page_banner', 'display', 'home_link', 'description', 'abbr_name', 'location_city', 'location_state', 'class_logo'])
```

Then, the next step would be to insert data. [It's already answered in this SO thread for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731207/inserting-multiple-dictionary-objects-into-a-mysql-database-using-python-and-mys). Similar options exist for other db backends, so, it should not be too hard.

Comment: Thanks Haleemur for an in-depth response. I was thinking of using a NoSQL DB because of 2 reasons. 1) There's way too much information in one object, which may or may not be useful, hence I was thinking of using a NoSQL DB because it can store the information with making a row and a column. 2) I've little experience in NoSQL and in a way I'll grasp the knowledge on the same.

Comment: I would like to hear your views on this . My endgoal is to make a web app with a list view and detail view by utilizing the public API of coursera. Reference URL:- https://www.coursera.org/courses

Comment: Seems like a sufficiently simple app that won't require much from its persistence layer. It would work well if you choose an appropriate NoSQL store or an RDBMS store. There might be slightly more work going into setting up your RDBMS, but you would still be up and running in an afternoon. If you want to use this to learn something you're less familiar with, then go for it!